# SQL Server 2008 R2 set up server issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Firstly apologies if this appears a really dumb question but after installing SQL Server 2008 R2 I can't actually use it and keep getting the below message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: named pipes provider , error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server , Error: 2)

I've tried googling how to set up a server for SQL Server 2008 R2 but the search results keep going to about SQL Server, not how to get it working!

To confirm I know how to use SQL Server 2008 R2 after the data is in it but I've never been involved with setting up a server and how to get it linked into SQL.  I don't know how to set up the server. I thought I'd be able to just use my hard drive?

Any help would be really welcomed :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at surface area config in SQL (and make sure the relevant protocols are enabled - hint:  there are a few place in there it has to explicitly be set to enabled - hunt).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable tcp\ip remote connections to sql server express already installed database with code or script(query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138172/enable-tcp-ip-remote-connections-to-sql-server-express-already-installed-databas)

Comment: Can you check SQL Server services are started. Also see TCP/IP protocol is enabled and Browser service is up and running